# loaded the "MainWindowController2" nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tabs

I saw the questions about this error.
But i believe i have a new one.
i have an application that runs on iPad and iPhone 4, but if i run it on iphone 3gs and switch to one specific tab it will crash with error 
"loaded the "MainWindowController2" nib but the view outlet was not set."
How can it be that it runs on one device and dont run on other device?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it would run on one device and not the other but that error is usually produced when the view outlet on the controller is not hooked up in Interface Builder. Load up the MainWindowController2 in the IB and make sure that the view outlet is hooked up correctly

Comment: The problem was wrong class name in Identity Inspector of File Owner.

Comment: When you open UIViewController xib file in resource editor, you can click on FileOwner and in Identity Inspector you will see that it liked to some Class, check out that it connected to correct class.Still i dont understand how it was running on one device and not running on other device.